# Scheduled Cron Job not running in Godaddy Share Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cron, hosting, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to install an investment script in my godaddy hosting, but when I program the cronjob that automatically schedules the return of interest for hours, days, weeks and months, it does not work. I tried to add a job to my GoDaddy hosting shared, but none of these ways has worked for me:

1. `php-cli /home/ruv2g9bvs29z/public_html/cronlab/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
2. `php72 /home/ruv2g9bvs29z/public_html/cronlab/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
3. `/usr/local/bin/php ~/public_html/ruv2g9bvs29z/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

4.`php /home/ruv2g9bvs29z/public_html/cronlab/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

The structure folder where the artisan file is located is like the image:

[image: Image1]

the cronjob programming instructions from the script provider:

[image: Image2]

The Kernel:

[image: Image3]

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: https://in.godaddy.com/help/create-cron-jobs-3548

Comment: instead of using `schedule:run` use your own command like, `30 19 * * * php /home/ruv2g9bvs29z/public_html/cronlab/artisan gen:sitemap  >> /dev/null 2>&1`